# How to enable longpress action to download on images in android WebView?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I want to enable the long press download action on images in the webview. That is the code snipped that I tried out for that:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registerForContextMenu(descriptionWebView); 
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      WebView.HitTestResult hitTestResult = descriptionWebView.getHitTestResult();
      switch (hitTestResult.getType()) {
        // ...
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register yout WebView for context menu. In yout activity registerForContextMenu(webView);

and after override onCreateContextMenu method shown bellow

```
WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    registerForContextMenu(webView);

    webView.loadUrl(HTTP_URL);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view, contextMenuInfo);

    final WebView.HitTestResult webViewHitTestResult = webView.getHitTestResult();

    if (webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
            webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

        contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Download Image From Below");

        contextMenu.add(0, 1, 0, "Save - Download Image")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        String DownloadImageURL = webViewHitTestResult.getExtra();

                        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(DownloadImageURL)){

                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadImageURL));
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Downloaded Successfully.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry.. Something Went Wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

or this is alternative

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    final WebView.HitTestResult result = browser.getHitTestResult();
    MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener handler = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // handle on context menu click
            return true;
        }
    };

    if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
            result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle(result.getExtra());
        menu.add(0, 666, 0, "Save Image").setOnMenuItemClickListener(handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Isamil Kilic I tried the shorter code too. It shows the same error at the same place

Comment: @SinanKara Please make sure you import it correctly. Because you need  this "import android.webkit.WebView;" for webViews. I tested and it is working .


http://prntscr.com/hoh5oi

Comment: @Isamil Kilic 
if you have nothing against it, could you share your project with meß So i can compare it against mine

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it. and this is my MainActivity Class. you can compare with your Activity
https://anotepad.com/notes/nqx8jr

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to try this out again :)

Comment: I tried it out and it finally worked. Thank you very much!